# how to install or use Xamarin with visual studio 2013

Tags: .net, xamarin

I have install vs13 and downloaded Xamarin but i don't know how to use Xamarin with visual studio 2013. can anybody explain whole process of installation and use with visual studio 2013

Comment: Have you tried just to install it? What problems have you faced?

Answer (score 3):

Once the installation is successful,  Start a new instance of  Visual Studio 2013 and got to **File-> New -> Project**, where you can see the section Android under Visual C# Templates.

[image]

Select Blank App (Android) Template, provide a proper name and location and then Click OK.  A default application is created in the solution explore with the following folder structure.

[image]

Lets have a look what is there inside.
Resource folder contains all the resources we create in the application like icons, axml files and importantly all the id’s (identifiers) that we assign to a controls in the axml page. So whenever a developer wants to access a control through its id he has to use like the following
?
1
Resource.Id.HelloWorldText
Where HelloWorldText is the id that is assigned to my TextView in my Main.axml file, which is explained below.
MainActivity.cs is nothing but a Page in windows world, so whenever you come across a file called activity then just remember it is a Page.

The MainActivity class contains an Attribute called Activity and has properties called Label, MainLauncher and Icon.
Label property specified the name of the application and here the applications is called as ANDROID_APP.
MainLauncher property specifies whether the current activity will be used as the Main Activity for the application, it is like the First page to be executed in the application.
Icon property specifies the icon for the Application.

For Complete tutorial refer [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-xamarin-part-1--cms-20987)

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio 2013, you may need the Xamarin.VisualStudio installer instead of the VS Tools installer.

If you reach out to contact@xamarin.com we can send you a link to download this.

There are a range of details guides provided in the documentation. The best place to start is here:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/

Comment: Sent you an email. Awaiting your response. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Sign into the Xamarin Site -> click your name at the top right -> Dashboard -> Downloads -> Download Xamarin for Windows -> install the downloaded file